# i3wm style notifications are appearing in unity

Tags: unity

I installed i3wm temporarily and switched back to Unity.

Now in Unity my desktop notifications are being served by whatever tool i3wm was using. This is what they look like:

[image]

How do I bring back Unity style notifications?

Answer (score 1):

There is no notification system provided by i3wm but it looks like it could be un software called `dunst`

uninstall it and you should be fine.